# How would one find a targeted specific value of a string variable with search methods?

Tags: javascript, string, methods

Currently going through different exercises over string variables. Right now, the current exercises deals with string methods. This is the variable that I'm working on.

```
var searchString = 'Lets search through this search string for the word, search';
```

What I did first was use this basic search method.

```
var searchIndex = searchString.search('search');
```

The result was a value of 5 returned to show the position of the first match. My question is, how do I go finding the second time search comes up in that string variable? How could I find the final time search comes up in the string variable?

Also, is it possible to use the search method to find all three times search came up at once and return all three?

Thanks in advance, everyone.

Kenneth

Comment: [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) lets you specify where to start the search from (`.search` does not).

Comment: This would give you all the matches, but not their positions: `'string'.match(/search/g)`

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown

Is this not the method necessary for what I want to achieve? At all?

Comment: @KennethStevenMcAuslandJr. I don't know. It isn't clear to me if you need their positions or not.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown

My bad, bud. I do need their positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search like this:

```js
var searchString = 'Lets search through this search string for the word, search';

function FindAllIndices(source, elem) {
    var indices = [];
    for(var pos = source.indexOf(elem); pos !== -1; pos = source.indexOf(elem, pos + 1)) {
        indices.push(pos);
    }
    return indices;
}

console.log(FindAllIndices(searchString, "search"));
```

Comment: Ahhhh. This is something a little interesting. Just trying to get clarification on what you did. I'll type out what I see and if there are parts that are missing and something is off, please explain and clarrify. What I see is that you created a function with multiple parameters. You then created another variable with an array in the functions logic. Underneath that specified variable, you created a loop with the first part of the for loops parameters that houses the variable with an indexOf method. Next in the for loop, another parameter specifying to remove the -1 and then a counter.

Comment: The counter on that for loop is a bit beyond my understand, the rest makes sense but I do need clarification on your counter for your loop @Pankaj Shukla.  How exactly does that counter work?

Comment: @Kenneth Steven McAusland Jr. The conditions are very similar to any for loop. First is to initialize, second is to check if the loop needs to be terminated and third is to modiy the counter. indexOf gives you first index of matching string. So, once that is added to the indices array, we set the pos to look for the string past the last index found until pos = -1 when the loop terminates.

Comment: Sir, you are one smart man. I've always written my loops in the standard (var i = 0; i < someThing.length; i++). Needed something like this to get a large refresh on what else I can do. 

Thank you :)